# What's the name of the component that allows a hot-swap power supply to slot-in and provides all the cables in a 1..4U server?

Tags: power-supply-unit, connector

In contrast to consumer grade PSUs, server PSUs sometimes come without cables. From what I gather, these are usually of the redundant variety or so called "1+1" configuration. I wander if there is a generic name for the component inside the servers into which these PSUs slot into.

I have seen different types of connectors, both more modern ones (gold finger) that look like a PCIe connector and older ones that are straight-up metal pins.

I have looked for "psu terminal", "psu termination", "psu connector", "power distributor", but I can't find the part that has all the molex, sata, atx 12v, 6pin GPU cables and that also connects to the PSU. I imagine there must be some standard for these hot-swappable PSUs.

What's the right search term to find this type of component, please?

```
┌─────────────┬─┬─┬─┬─────┐
│ PSU         │>│?│:│┼┼┼┼┼│
│ PSU         │>│?│:│┼┼┼┼┼│
│────────── ──┘ └─┘ │┼┼┼┼┼│
│┌────────────┐  : :│┼┼┼┼┼│
││mobo      ..│..: :│┼┼┼┼┼│
││       .....│....:│┼┼┼┼┼│
│└────────────┘     │┼┼┼┼┼│
└───────────────────┴─────┘
```

- the dots are cables
- the angle brackets are the gold-finger slot-in connectors

**I'm looking for the part between the cables and the PSUs, if there is such a part in a server.**

(I have seen some wonky solutions in workstations that plug into the mobo and go from there).

Comment: There's no universal part. It's custom for every vendor. I don't think you'll find this type of component as a generic part, but rather as part of a system for redundant powersupplies.

Comment: My question is not off topic. The name for such a part would be something like "the motherboard" in practical terms and some cases or "dedicated power converter" as a generic term in another range of cases. Yet still, in some cases, the task of splitting the power could be done by the "the PSU outer cage". The redundant modules slide into this PSU case/cage/box/unit.

Comment: Just because someone is unfamiliar with the terminology and conventions in a specific field, does not make a question they ask off-topic.

Comment: I don't understand what either the question or the answer has to do with managing IT in a business environment. The answer as it stands goes on about power supplies - including tangents such as buck-boost converters.. So yes. I consider off topic on this site.

Comment: That's probably because you have a very limited imagination, or maybe the issue is that I think "managing IT" includes taking care of the servers, and this site is more only about the software. Think of it as a generic question. "How do I run a bunch of servers in a small business", "What happens with the old hardware when we get new stuff in, is it interchangeable?".

Answer (score 0):

These sources claim the device I'm asking about is called:

- PDB or Power Distribution Board ([A DELL R410 server with a redundant PSU and A PDB](https://youtu.be/9VS5j4-QHnA?t=481))
- ... reserved for future (supermicro)
- ... reserved for future (intel)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was asking about. If I come across other names for it from different vendors, I'll expand the list. Or you can help me if you feel like it ;)

Answer (score -1):

The (subjectively) best way to figure out how to use newer PSU with old components is to get familiar with different vendor's equipment by reading the manuals for the relevant parts and by browsing for compatible parts on their website, or browsing for individual components in pre-configured solutions. If you have friends working at big data centers, you can probably ask them for hints on what to look for.

To be fair, this is no small task, it's probably easier to find older PSUs and use those with old systems. Then there are specialty devices for converting voltage called "buck converter 12v to 5v" or similar, which you can research and look into integrating with your project.

There is no easy way to figure out how to connect a modern-12-volt-only PSU to an older system with ATX12V / EPS12V connectors. Server part manufacturers have been using 12-v PSUs for some time now.

Gamer's Nexus published an article a while back about this gradual transition potentially affecting home users in the future:

> We should start with this notice: 12VO, in a sense, isn’t actually new. Companies like Dell, HP, and Lenovo -- especially HP -- have been using a form of power supplies with only 12V in their systems for a long time now. In these systems, the motherboards are outfitted with all the DC-to-DC bucks and boosts necessary for drives. Although these have existed, they weren’t standardized and often used proprietary connectors or power supplies.

The full article provides an intro and lays out a bunch of reasons for the switch and so on.

- https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/3568-intel-atx-12vo-spec-explained-what-manufacturers-think

Examples:

- Supermicro PDB-PT112-2420 Power Distributor Netzteil-Backplane für 1HE Racks
- Supermicro PDB-PT848-8824 Power Distributor Netzteil-Backplane für SC848 Rack
- Supermicro PDB-PT933-8824 Power Distributor Netzteil-Backplane für SC833 / SC932
- Supermicro CSE-PT822-PD500, SP502-2S Power Distributor Netzteil-Backplane